# Delphi, Android & SQLite encryption?

Tags: android, delphi, sqlite

A few years ago I created an Android app using trial versions of XE8 and XE10.
The app used FireDAC and SQLite and it worked pretty much as I expected.
I am trying to revive and update the app but I am having trouble with SQLite.
First it errow-ed out with 'no such table'. After trying some things found on the Internet
  the DAC started returning "[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: Cipher: DB is not encrypted".
The app & SQLite run just fine on windows but not on Android.

Did something change vis-a-vis encryption?
What do I have to do to get my app the work again?

Thanks...Dan'l

Comment: We don't know anything about what you have done. You'll need to provide a [mcve]. Also, there is no such thing as XE10.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know the real cause but the solution is to extract and re-create the database.